# Selecting several nonsequential rows in table

Tags: php, select, field, row

I have 18 rows in one of my tables with several columns. I would like to extract the data from several different non-sequential rows and echo them individually on different parts of my page.

For example, let's say I wanted to pick records 5, 9 and 13 from column_1 and echo them to the page in different places. How would I accomplish this? Would I need to perform one query each to retrieve these unique fields? Here is my code so far:

```
// $database connect code, blah blah...

$sql = "SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE (not sure if something should go here)";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

maybe some code here, not sure...

};
```

Doing so with ALL of the records in a specific column is easy using a while loop, but that's not what I'm after. I thought there may have been a way to cherry pick the specific row with an associative array like $fetchRow['row']['row_number'], but that doesn't appear to work. Performing one query for each unique instance seems awfully inefficient.

I'm familiar with how to retrieve things from the database and display them on the page. I'm intermediate level, but this has gotten me stumped.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is beginner, not intermediate. Look up the MySQL manual to understand what syntax is allowed after WHERE. You would put "WHERE id='5' OR id='9' OR id='13'" to pull only those 3 records, assuming the column you are using to differentiate the rows is called id.

Comment: What is the common thing between these rows? id, price, name, title, tag, firstName etc. Whatever is the common field needs to go into your WHERE clause. like WHERE title='aerosmith' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE column_1 IN (5, 9, 13)";
```

Or if you'd rather do it with a PHP array, something like this:

```
$cols = array(5,9,13);
$in_cols = implode(',', $cols);
$sql = "SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE column_1 IN ({$in_cols}})";
```

If you're going to use #2, make sure you properly sanitize/prepare the statement before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

However, since you only have 18 rows... I would store all the result set in an array and use this array to echo the rows elements I want on the page. That way you do not have the overhead of typing the supplementary code (the best code is no code) and having to retrieve the specific rows you want. Furthermore, would you ever want to retrieve other records, there would be no need to modify your query.